# Help finding equation of circle given another circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Please help me find the standard equation of the circle passing through the point $(-3,1)$ and containing the points of intersection of the circles
$$
x^2 + y^2 + 5x = 1
$$
and 
$$
x^2 + y^2 + y = 7
$$

I don't know how to begin, I am used to tangent lines or other points, but I don't know what is visually going on here. I can find the two centres C(h,k) of the given equations, but what is the conceptual trick to equate that to the equation in question? Please provide a step by step solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is as follows:
Let $C_1=0$ and $C_2=0$ be the equations of the two given circles. Then consider the curve $C_1 + \lambda C_2=0$. Depending on the value of $\lambda$ this can represent a circle that passes through the intersection of the two circles. Now to get the appropriate value of $\lambda$ We can substitute the third point $(-3,1)$ that lies on the circle we are after.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this form cannot represent $C_2$.

Comment: @Awesome Good point.